# How to get the arguments from getopt to work together

Tags: c, unix, switch-statement, arguments, getopt

I want to be able to use every argument (-S, -s, -f) and them be able to be used together. -S prints the files in the folder and their size... -s prints the files if they are >= the file size provided by the argument -f finds all the files with the given substring.

How would I get these to work together? Right now, my code does all of this separately.

```
while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "Ss:f:")) != -1){
    switch(c){
        case 'S':
        // No clue how to make them work together.
            printf("Case: S\n");
            printf("option -%c with argument '%s'\n", c, argv[optind]);
            printDIR(cwd, case_S);
            break;
        case 's':
            printf("Case: s\n");
            printf("option -%c with argument '%s'\n", c, optarg);
            printDIR(cwd, case_s);
            break;
        case 'f':
            printf("Case: f\n");
            printf("option -%c with argument '%s'\n", c, optarg);
            printDIR(cwd, case_f);
            break;
        default:
            printf("...");
    }
}
```

printDIR is a pointer function which is why I have cwd(which is the directory) and case_S and so on.

I want to be able to say... './search -S -s 1024 -f tar'. This should recursively search the current directory and print the size of the file if it is >= 1024 and if the file has the substring 'tar' in it. But I also want it to work even if I don't provide all arguments.

This is my first time trying anything like this so I'm new to trying to make UNIX commands and using getopt args.

Comment: Let me know if any more code or context is needed.

Comment: So by "work together", you mean that you want to implement one _generic_ function for listing files and filter the list of files using a parametrized filter? What do you mean by work together? Why not just `case 'S': print_all_files_and_folders(); case 's': print_filter_grater_then(atoi(optarg));` etc. Why the `case_S` `case_s` (just use `'S'` and `'s'`...)?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to be able to say... ./search -S -s 1024 -f tar 
this should recursively search the current directory and print the size of the file if it is >= 1024 and if the file has the substring 'tar' in it. But i also want it to work even if i don't provide all arguments.

Comment: Process the options without doing any actions.  Only when you've finished processing the options, with no errors, do you think about doing anything like calling `printDIR()`.  You'll need more options to the function, probably, or a bit-encoding of the options.  It seems odd to be using `argv[optind]` where you otherwise use (more correctly/conventionally) `optarg`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of using comments to add information. Please describe your example use cases in the question. BTW: Option 'S' is specified without argument in `"Ss:f:"`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How would I go about checking each argument before doing what is needed to do. Should i create flags like... caseS = 1 and if it is then i know to print the size of the file? and yeah it is weird but i was getting an error if i didn't do it that way...

Comment: Yes.  And 'minimum_size = 0` and modify it with `-s 1024`.  And `const char *filter = "";` and then modify that with `-s tar`.  Etc.  Often, these are global variables — but if you can avoid that by passing them to the function, that is better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Converting parts of some of my comments into an answer.*</sup>

You should process the options without doing any actions. Only when you've finished processing the options, with no errors, do you think about doing anything like calling `printDIR()`. You'll probably need more arguments to the function, or use global variables.

You'd have a flag such as:

```
int recursive = 0;
```

which you would set to `1` if the search was to be recursive. And `int minimum_size = 0;` and modify it with `-s 1024`. And `const char *filter = "";` and then modify that with `-s tar`. Etc. Often, these are global variables — but if you can avoid that by passing them to the function, that is better.

Your function might then become:

```
int printDIR(const char *cwd, int recursive, int minimum, const char *filter);
```

and you'd call it with the appropriately set local variables.  Note that you should check the conversion from string to integer before calling `printDIR()`.

If there are non-option arguments, you'd process them after the option handling with:

```
for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    printDIR(argv[i], recursive, minimum_size, filter);
```

Comment: This is great! I have one question though. -S will print the size and -s will not. -s checks the size but will not print the size unless -S is an argument. What would be the best way to approach this.

Comment: Use some conditional code in the `printDIR()` function.  When it comes time to calculate and print the size, look at the options to decide whether it is relevant to do it.